# What should be done if Cloud option is not available in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, openshift

I to learn how to deploy docker container in openshift from intelliJ. However, I went through the [Jetbrain](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-openshift-deployment.html) page for adding plugin and then I went to "working with a [cloud platform](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-clouds.html#d889242e61) page". However, when I open IntelliJ `preference-Build, Execution, Deployment` I don't see Clouds option. How do I enable this option?

I am using IntelliJ Community 2018.1.6 Build #IC-181.55407.7

Preference Tab screenshot
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the information box in the top right corner of the page you've linked to says, the functionality is only available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.